# confusion of comma operator in variable initializations

Tags: c++, initialization, initializer-list, comma-operator, uniform-initialization

If i'm not wrong, (1,2,3,4,5) expression will evaluate to 5( the order of evaluation is from left to right), then why `int m({1,2,3,4,5})` is not being compiled fine?

Following is the compile-time error message.
 `cannot convert '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'int' in initialization`

Don't mind, i'm new to C++, please correct my understanding, I just know that an expression with comma operator is evaluated from left to right and the rightmost value is then returned in the evaluation, but( according to my wrong understanding) here the inner expression should be evaluated to 5 and m should be initialized with value 5 fine.

I'm using Dev-C++ with TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64 bit release( i don't know how to find the running version of c++, whether it's c++11 or earlier version).

Please guide me.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to show a minimal reproducible example where it's not compiling. Also please mention the compiler version you're using.

Comment: [Works for me](https://godbolt.org/z/j7PMf59W1)

Comment: Wild guess - you're using C++03?  Does simply `int m{5};` compile?

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work" you didn't say what happened.  Wrong result?  Comile time error?  If so, what was it?  It should work.  Are you using an old c++ compiler, or language level before c++11?  The curly-brace initializer syntax was expanded to work on `int` in c++11.  Before that, it would be a syntax error.  See: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5W9hzrs9j

Comment: If you include the full error message in your question, people might be better able to figure out what went wrong. Those messages tend to be written to tell you exactly why your code is invalid. Well, maybe not yet *you* as someone new to C++, but eventually, once you ask people to explain the error messages to you. Of course, that would require that the error message be in the question...

Comment: Based on the error message, the suggestion by Drew Dormann is worth trying. Think about it. You believe that `m{(1,2,3,4,5)}` should evaluate to the same result as `m{5}`, right? So before blaming the comma operator, verify the stuff around the comma operator. Same error message, right? Your question should not be about the comma operator, but about this form of initialization. (Your gcc version defaults to compiling for C++98. It supports a higher version with the `-std=c++11` command line option.)